# Norm, limit, and max norm

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

For any $\vec{u} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ prove that
$$\lim_{p\to \infty} \|\vec{u}\|_p = \max (|u_1|, |u_2|)$$

Then, when $p\to\infty$ we get $||\vec{u}||_{\infty}$. And we get the max norm, $\|\vec{u}\|_{\infty} = \max \sum_{i=1}^n|u_i|$

How do I get from here to $\max (|u_1|, |u_2|)$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose that $|u_1| \geq |u_2|$. Then 
$$
\|u\|_p = |u_1| \left[ 1 + \left(\frac{|u_2|}{|u_1|}\right)^p \right]^{1/p}
$$
Now, why will this converge to $|u_1| = \max(|u_1|,|u_2|)$?

Comment: $$
\dfrac{\|u\|_p}{\left[ 1 + \left(\frac{|u_2|}{|u_1|}\right)^p \right]^{1/p}} = |u_1| 
$$

Comment: I think what you want to notice is that $$\lim_{p \to \infty} \left[ 1 + \left( \frac{|u_1|}{|u_2|} \right)^p \right]^{1/p} = 1$$.

Comment: what about the top??

Comment: at the top we would have the infinity norm, right? and $||u||_{\infty} = max\{|u_1|,\ldots ,|u_i|\}$

Comment: $$\lim_{p \to \infty} \|u\|_p = |u_1| \, \lim_{p \to \infty} \left[ 1 + \left(\frac{|u_1|}{|u_2|} \right)^p \right]^{1/p} = |u_1| = \max\{|u_1|,|u_2|\} = \|u\|_{\infty}$$

Comment: I see... $|u_1|$ is just a constant. How is it equal to max? Sorry, but I want to understand everything!

Comment: At the beginning we assumed that $|u_1| \geq |u_2|$ and therefore $|u_1| = \max\{|u_1|,|u_2|\}$. If instead you assume that $|u_2| > |u_1|$ you can make a similar argument. Note that for positive numbers $a$ and $b$, $\left(\frac{a}{b} \right)^p$ remains finite if and only if $a \leq b$.

Comment: Right! Awesome! thx! :)